Construction of a header containing the current titles or MultiPage
I use dart-pdf to create multi-page documents, but I haven't found a solution for displaying level 0, 1 and 2 headings in the header, for example.
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

header(pw.Context context) => pw.ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: pw.BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 2 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        child: pw.Row(
          children: [
            pw.Expanded(
              child: pw.Column(
                children: [
                  pw.Text("Titles heres !"),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            pw.Image(
              pw.MemoryImage(
                File(
                  "myLogo.png",
                ).readAsBytesSync(),
              ),
              fit: pw.BoxFit.contain,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
footer(pw.Context context) => pw.ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: pw.BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
        child: pw.Column(
          children: [
            pw.Divider(color: PdfColors.grey, thickness: 1.5),
            pw.Expanded(
              child: pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Expanded(
                    child: pw.Text(
                      style: pw.TextStyle(color: PdfColors.grey, fontSize: 8),
                      "Row 1\n"
                      "Row 2",
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Text(
                    style: pw.TextStyle(color: PdfColors.grey, fontSize: 8),
                    "Page ${context.pageNumber}/${context.pagesCount}",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );

final pdf = pw.Document();
pdf.addPage(
    pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
      header: (context) => header(context),
      footer: (context) => footer(context),
      build: (context) => [
        pw.Header(level: 0, text: "Title 1"),
        pw.Header(level: 1, text: "Title 1.1"),
        pw.Paragraph(text: "Sample"),
        pw.NewPage(),
        pw.Header(level: 0, text: "Title 2"),
        pw.Header(level: 1, text: "Title 2.1"),
        pw.Paragraph(text: "Sample"),
        pw.NewPage(),
        pw.Header(level: 1, text: "Title 2.2"),
        pw.Header(level: 2, text: "Title 2.2.1"),
        pw.Paragraph(text: "Sample 2"),
      ],
    ),
  ); // Page
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.MultiPage(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      orientation: pw.PageOrientation.portrait,
      margin: pw.EdgeInsets.all(1 * PdfPageFormat.cm),
      header: (context) => header(context),
      footer: (context) => footer(context),
      build: (context) => [
        pw.TableOfContent(),
      ],
    ),
    index: 1,
  );
[...]

I tried to manipulate the pageLabels but without success.
I haven't found a similar request either in the API documentation or here, which is why I'm asking for the community's help!
